# SKSpritenode stay on Path (PhysicSimulation)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics, cgpath

Hello I want that a SKSpriteNode stays on a CGPath, but it should not be an animation and the SpriteNode should move on the path by forces like in game gravity .
Thanks for Help

```
let path  = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, self.size.width/2,  self.size.height/2, 100, CGFloat(M_PI), CGFloat(M_PI*2), false)
```

Comment: Is this _inside_ an area defined by the `CGPath` or is it only allow to move along the lines of the `CGPath`?

Comment: it should only move along the the path @Gliderman

Comment: Could you give us the code for the `CGPath`?  Are you just trying to lock it to move up and down, or something more complicated, like an arc?

Comment: @Gliderman It should move along the arc

Comment: You may be able to do something like give the `SKSpriteNode` a small circle physics body, and then with the arc, make it so that it is a channel that fits the small circle instead.  At least, that's what I would do.  You could then place the `SKSpriteNode` inside the channel, and turn on `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` so that it can't escape.  Would that work for your purposes?